# Gazebo: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Linking CXX executable gazebo-non-ros
libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0: undefined reference to `clock_gettime' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[4]: *** [server/gazebo-non-ros] Error 1 make[4]: Leaving directory` /home/klapfer/ros/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/build'
make[3]: *** [server/CMakeFiles/gazebo-exec.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/klapfer/ros/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/build' make[2]: *** [all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/klapfer/ros/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/build'
make[1]: *** [installed] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/klapfer/ros/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo'
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:32 (message):
Build of Gazebo failed

I just changed computer this morning and when trying to compile the gazebo_simulator I get this error. It is computer depended, but I have no clue where the error comes from.

I hope I can find some help here. Thank you all in advance.

Reinhard

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28689/gazebo:-undefined-reference-to-%60clock_gettime%27/) by [ReiniK](https://answers.ros.org/users/1841/reinik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReiniK](https://answers.ros.org/users/1841/reinik/) on 2012-02-28**:
Note: I am tryng to compile the latest version taken from
https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/electric/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Modifying the file:
~/ros/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/CMakeLists.txt helped.

```
target_link_libraries( gazebo-exec ${libtool_library}
                               ${gazeboserver_link_libs} 
                               ${boost_libraries} 
                               ${assimp_libraries} 
                               ${freeimage_library} 
                               gazebo_server
                               gazebo_rendering
                               gazebo_av-shared
                               gazebo_gui
                               gazebo_physics
                               gazeboshm 
                               assimp
                               pthread
                               -lrt
```

)

But is is not optimal and the changes are undone when cleaning the project.
If someone knows a solution to this it would be nice to share it here.

Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [ReiniK](https://answers.ros.org/users/1841/reinik/) with karma: 84 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-28**:
this has change has been added to the repo, and will be there in the next release 1.4.12 (https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/hg/rev/2ab1039c959f)